# pyspark: Compare 2 large pyspark dataframes

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have 2 pyspark dataframes with 50 (columns) * 700,000 (rows) of data.

I want to compare 2 dataframes. Any suggestions for comparison tools? Thanks.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compare **all 700k rows** then Use **`.exceptAll`**(with duplicates) (or) **`.subtract`**(without duplicates) built in function to compare two dataframes.

`(or)`

If you want to **compare only some sample rows** then use window **`row_number`** function with **`orderBy`** clause and select only required rows then use **`.exceptAll`** (or) **`.subtract`** functions.

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,'a'),(2,'b')],['id','name'])
df1=spark.createDataFrame([(1,'a')],['id','name']
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.exceptAll(df1).show()
#+---+----+
#| id|name|
#+---+----+
#|  2|   b|
#+---+----+

df1.exceptAll(df).show()
#+---+----+
#| id|name|
#+---+----+

#or if you need to check only specific columns
df.select("id").exceptAll(df1.select("id")).show()
#+---+
#| id|
#+---+
#|  2|
#+---+


df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(1,'a')],['id','name'])
df.subtract(df1).show()
#+---+----+
#| id|name|
#+---+----+
#|  2|   b|
#+---+----+
df.exceptAll(df1).show()
#+---+----+
#| id|name|
#+---+----+
#|  2|   b|
#|  1|   a|
#+---+----+
```